# Is there a way to configure "Copy File Path" in Sublime Text?

Tags: windows, bash, sublime-text-3

I'm using the new(ish) [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about), in conjunction with Sublime Text. I'd like to be able to specify that "Copy File Path" in Sublime's context menu should give me a Unix-like file path (for use in Bash on Ubuntu) rather than a Windows file path (as it does by default).

Is there any way (plugin or otherwise) of configuring Sublime Text to use file path formats other than the OS default?